# How to use XMLHttpRequest using VBA with object data

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

I am currently trying to make a msgbox for a userform that I am making that responds with the data from the below javascript using VBA

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: app.global.AppPath + 'Dashboard/GetComments',
                async: false,
                data: {
                    id: 1015998
                },
                success: function(result) {}
});
```

VBA Code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim strUrl As String
        strUrl = "https://charter.osp-cloud.com/ATOM/Dashboard/GetComments"

    Set hReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        With hReq
            .Open "GET", strUrl, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
            .Send "id=1015998"
        End With
    MsgBox hReq.ResponseText
End Sub
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Is it because I am not sending a object `.Send "{id: 1015998}"`?

UPDATE:
upon a little more research I found that maybe parsejson might work but I cant seem to get it to recognize that there is an object

```
Dim JSON As Dictionary
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson("{""id"": 1015998}")
```

Error says "Object Required"

response pulled is below

`The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetComments(Int32)' in 'EZTRACKER.Controllers.DashboardController'.`

Comment: Did you try adding the brackets?  Typically in json the keys are quoted.

Comment: @TimWilliams Nope, didn't work :/

Comment: "didn't work" isn't a very useful description of what happens when you run your code...   `.Send "{""id""=""1015998""}"` should work.

Comment: @TimWilliams I have read through these and found that none of these are having the same issues as mine. Maybe it has something to do with the server (url) wanting a int32 rather than technically a string

Answer (score 0):

You use POST not GET when sending data in the request body:

Also fix your content type

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim strUrl As String, hreq
        strUrl = "https://charter.osp-cloud.com/ATOM/Dashboard/GetComments"

    Set hreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        With hreq
            .Open "POST", strUrl, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
            .Send "{""id"":1015998}"
        End With
    Debug.Print hreq.ResponseText
End Sub
```

or if you want to use GET then the data goes in the querystring:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Click()
    Dim strUrl As String, hreq
        strUrl = "https://charter.osp-cloud.com/ATOM/Dashboard/GetComments?id=1015998"

    Set hreq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        With hreq
            .Open "GET", strUrl, False
            .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
            .Send 
        End With
    Debug.Print hreq.ResponseText
End Sub
```